# uib-carousel causing inifinite loop

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the following markup in my html:

```
<div style="height: 305px">
  <div uib-carousel active="false" interval="50000" no-wrap="true">
    <div uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in shoes track by slide._id" index="slide._id">
      <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Slide {{slide._id}}</h4>
        <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Every time I run navigate to this view, I get an infinite loop. It seems (from the console logs I have) that the controller is loading again and again. When I comment out these lines, the rest of the page loads just fine. Is there any reason uib-carousel would cause a reload like this? Am I implementing this correctly? Here is my controller code:

```
myApp.controller( 'myShoesController', [ '$http', '$location', function( $http, $location ) {

var vm = this;
vm.shoes = [];


console.log( 'myShoesController connected' );

vm.myShoes = function() {
  console.log( 'running vm.myShoes' );
    $http ({
      method:'GET',
      url:'/shoes'
    }).then(function success( response ) {
      vm.shoes = response.data;
      console.log( 'response from shoes', response );
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('error returning shoes:', err);
    });
  };

  vm.myShoes();
}]);
```

Here are my main `app.js` file with routes (what I originally thought might be the cause, but seem fine):

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

/// Routes ///
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

  $routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
      templateUrl: '/views/home.html',
      controller: "LoginController as lc"
    })
    .when('/register', {
      templateUrl: '/views/register.html',
      controller: "LoginController as lc"
    })
    .when('/user', {
      templateUrl: '/views/user.html',
      controller: "UserController as uc"
    })
    .when( '/addItem', {
      templateUrl: '/views/addItem.html',
      controller: "addItemController as aic"
    })
    .when( '/myShoes', {
      templateUrl: '/views/myShoes.html',
      controller: "myShoesController as msc"
    })
    .when( '/selectShoes', {
      templateUrl: '/views/selectShoes.html',
      controller: "selectShoesController as ssc"
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: 'home'
    });

}]);
```

And my dependencies:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/ui-bootstrap.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

I am using angular 1.6

Comment: Can you provide a working demo?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your data looks like, but after creating a plunker and playing around, it looks like your problem might be the `index="slide._id"`. I found that if there is not an index value of `0` in one of your slides, and if the indexes are not sequential, then the carousel goes haywire.

I think it's safe to say that array rules apply to the `index` attribute. That is to say, that the values must start at zero and be sequential, just like an array accessor.

It might be better to just use `$index` for the `index` attribute, or make sure your data has ID's that are sequential and that start at `0`.

```
<div style="height: 305px">
  <div uib-carousel="" active="false" interval="5000" no-wrap="true">
    <div uib-slide="" ng-repeat="slide in shoes track by $index" index="$index">
      <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;" />
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h4>Slide {{slide._id}}</h4>
        <p>{{slide.text}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/wMtj7tt8M3AN3e7RMMfk?p=preview